# How does SonarQube line coverage analysis work?

Tags: java, performance, unit-testing, sonarqube, code-coverage

I have been wondering how exactly does the SonarQube analysis work. If one class (in my case a java class) has been tested by multiple test classes, does sonar show all of the combined and common covered line between the tests?
For example, TestClass1 covers 65% and TestClass2 covers 30% and if we combine both of them its 95%, but 20% of the lines are covered by both test classes so we can deduct that and be left with 75% coverage. Is this a valid process.
Also in the SonarQube can i see from which test each line has been covered?
I guess this topic is a bit dodgy but bear with me please.
Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter how many tests cover the same line of the code under test.  The measurement of coverage looks at the number of lines covered and the number of lines in the code under test. You won't be able to tell which tests covered a line.